# New expo-cli dev-client (SDK 48) returns a manifest that cannot be parsed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas, code-push

When I run `npx expo start --dev-client`, both our android and iOS app throws an error when selecting the dev server, with the message:

`Error loading app. Value ----------------------------224819657222108214122421 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` on Android.

`Error loading app. Couldn't parse the manifest. The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format` on iOS.

When I hit the dev server url (eg. http://192.168.1.179:8081) manually to obtain the manifest, I can see it is indeed starting with the above value, as it contains some meta-data, eg.

```
----------------------------783506567945418080873744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="manifest"
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":"203368a8-dcbe-45a6-afba-0a1e76018e5d","createdAt":"2023-08-24T06:02:54.108Z","runtimeVersion":"1.0.6","launchAsset":{"key":"bundle","contentType":"application/javascript","url":"http://192.168.1.179:8081/index.bundle?platform=none&dev=true&hot=false"},"assets":[],"metadata":{},"extra":{"eas":{"projectId":"cc2c7913-15b1-4e18-aa87-a29294e12ac9"},"expoClient":...............,"packagerOpts":{"dev":true},"mainModuleName":"index","__flipperHack":"React Native packager is running"},"scopeKey":"@speciesplus/speciesplus"}}
----------------------------783506567945418080873744--
...
```

It's an **expo managed** project and I use `npx expo prebuild --clean` to build the native **ios/** and **android/** files, after which I build the app with debug build variant/schema with Android Studio (v2022.3.1) and Xcode (v14.2 (14C18)). But it gives me the same error even when building the app with `eas build --platform android --profile development --local` with the following **eas profile**:

```
"development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
```

**My stack is:**

1. `expo` `48.0.18`
2. `react` `18.2.0`
3. `react-native` `0.71.8`
4. `node` `16.18.1` / `npm` `8.19.2`
5. I also use `react-native-code-push` `7.1.0` with the respective plugin and patch it it's of some use

I've tried to run the dev-client expo app on both Android and iOS but upon connecting to the expo metro server it gives me the above mentioned error.

I expect the app to open without that error.

Comment: I've solved it, it was something I had in app.json: 
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/cc2c7913-15b1-4e18-aa87-a29294******"
    }. I've removed it and now it works.